# Flask app not collecting updated POST info from client in WHILE loop

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I have an issue where my python client is sending POST requests to a flask server, and it will update the variables on the server, initially, but if I introduce a FOR loop into the client, it will never update.  Any ideas as to why?  Again, if I remove the for loop on the client and run it manually, it will update the POST Variables on the server every time.  You can see from the output that the time stamps are not updating...  I have no clue as to why it will update without the for loop, unless it's not closing the session out?  Thanks in advance!

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os, csv
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from tabledef import *
from tabledef2 import *
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("client.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    result = c.execute('SELECT * from clientdb')
    host_array = []
    for i in result:
        #print str(i).split("'")[1]
        host_array.append(str(i))
        #host_array.append(str(i).split("'")[1])
    return render_template('home1.html', message=host_array)

@app.route('/check', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def check():
    try:
        host = request.form['hostname']
        ip = request.form['ip']
        ipex = request.form['ipex']
        timestamp = request.form['timestamp']
        code = request.form['code']
        print host, ip, ipex, timestamp, code
        return render_template('home1.html')
    except IOError or ValueError or IOError.errno as e:
        print "There was an error!"
        return render_template('home1.html', message=e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.secret_key = os.urandom(12)
    app.run(host='x.x.x.x', port=7000)
```

client.py

```
import socket, requests
from time import strftime
import time
import urllib2
timestamp = strftime("%m-%d-%Y / %H:%M:%S")
hostname = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
ipex = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
while 1:
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        URL = "http://10.1.1.33:7000/check"
        payload = {
            'hostname': "Server 1",
            'ip':  ip,
            'ipex': ipex,
            'timestamp': timestamp,
            'code': 10
        }
        session = requests.session()
        r = requests.post(URL, data=payload)
        #print r.cookies
     except socket.error:
        print ("Connection was refused, trying to reconnect...")
```

Output

```
* Running on http://10.1.1.33:7000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Server 1 10.1.1.33 68.115.121.98 01-16-2017 / 12:14:08 10
10.1.1.33 - - [16/Jan/2017 12:14:11] "POST /check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
10.1.1.33 - - [16/Jan/2017 12:14:14] "POST /check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Server 1 10.1.1.33 68.115.121.98 01-16-2017 / 12:14:08 10
10.1.1.33 - - [16/Jan/2017 12:14:17] "POST /check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Server 1 10.1.1.33 68.115.121.98 01-16-2017 / 12:14:08 10
10.1.1.33 - - [16/Jan/2017 12:14:20] "POST /check HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Server 1 10.1.1.33 68.115.121.98 01-16-2017 / 12:14:08 10
```

Comment: Are you referring to `while 1: time.sleep(3)`? `timestamp = strftime("%m-%d-%Y / %H:%M:%S")` is calculated outside of the `while` loop, so it would appear it could never get updated.

Comment: Yes, and it has the same value on each iteration of your `while` loop. If you don't recalculate it _within_ the while loop, then it's forever stuck with whatever value it had going into the loop. As Daniel's answer says, this is not to do with Flask, this is standard to Python

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Flask.

Your client sends the same timestamp each time, because you define it outside the loop and never update it. Move the  `strftime` call inside the while loop.

Comment: I feel like the biggest dummy in the world right now!